# Solution For node_modules Not Appearing In My Directory After Running npm install?

Tags: javascript, terminal, node-modules, npm-install

I have downloaded the starting code for a task from Codecademy and when I executed npm install in my terminal I get this:

```
"PC:\Users\jacma\OneDrive\Desktop\Jake's Folder\Coding Projects\react_router_v6_lesson_starting_code> npm install

up to date, audited 17 packages in 1s

found 0 vulnerabilities"
```

yet the node_modules folder doesn't appear anywhere in the vscode folders?

Does anyone have any ideas of a solution for this?

this is the package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "tech-news",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
      "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
      "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
      "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
      "react": "^18.2.0",
      "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
      "react-markdown": "^8.0.3",
      "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
      "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
      "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
      "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
      ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
      "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
      ],
      "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Any solutions greatly appreciated!

I have downloaded the starting code for a task from Codecademy and when I executed npm install in my terminal I get this:

```
"PC:\Users\jacma\OneDrive\Desktop\Jake's Folder\Coding Projects\react_router_v6_lesson_starting_code> npm install

up to date, audited 17 packages in 1s

found 0 vulnerabilities"
```

yet the node_modules folder doesn't appear anywhere in the vscode folders?

Comment: node_modules is may be hidden. If you are using windows, open the folder, click the `view` button on the top bar and then tick the box that says `hidden items`

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The only thing you mention is that the IDE doesn't display something, this is not really a programming related problem. Is the folder present in the file system?